Why does my phone not meet "Play Strong Integrity"?
My phone is a HTC One A9, I have tried to ask this question in many ways but it is not clear to me if my phone has been tampered or not..
It is not rooted and as much as i can see it does not has custom rom.

Your HTC One A9 might not meet Play due to outdated firmware.Even if the phone isn't rooted, it could fail integrity checks if it has unofficial updates, security issues, or lacks required security certifications.

can you provide a link where Google states that Play Integrity can be used to detect "security issues, or lacks required security certifications"? To my knowledge the only requirement for the device is that it passes the Google Android compatibility tests and is "registered" at Google - but that is the minimum requirement for all official Google Android device that are shipped with Google apps.

@Naira Nicol So it could mean the device is just old, not tampered?

@Robert From https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/verdicts#device-integrity-field: "The app is running on a device that passes basic system integrity checks. The device may not meet Android compatibility requirements and may not be approved to run Google Play services. For example, the device may be running an unrecognized version of Android, may have an unlocked bootloader, or may not have been certified by the manufacturer."

@DaleunSeun I still don't see where you get the "security issues". Because that is usually the irony if you install a custom ROM because of security reasons (patched vulnerabilities) you loose Play Integrity and thus some apps refuse to run because of insecure OS.

@Robert I did not install a ROM, I want to verify if someone else did.

@DaleunSeun my comments here are just about this answer and have nothing to do with your question or what you are trying to do.
